# Cant include integers in my print command without them adding

Tags: python

Cant include integers in my print command without them adding  (line 7)

```
# Calc test started 8/3/20

def add():
    add_x = int(input("Number 1: "))
    add_y = int(input("Number 2: "))

    def add_numbers(x, y):
        return x + y
    sum = add_numbers(add_x, add_y)
    print(add_x + add_y + sum) 

add()
```

Comment: Try `print(add_x, add_y, sum)`.

Comment: You'd probably be pretty upset if `return x + y` concatenated the numbers as strings instead of adding them. I know I would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are integers they by using the `+` operator you are adding them together, whereas if you use the `+` operator with strings they will be concatenated. To convert them replace line 7 with the following code:
`print(str(add_x) + str(add_y) + str(sum))`